# how to eliminate same date values in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

If the table has the following data

```
 num   | date_       |           s            | i_id 
-------+-------------+------------------------+---------
     1 | 2013-12-12  | (2,1,2013-12-12,80.56) |       2
     1 | 2013-12-12  | (3,1,2013-12-12,70.56) |       3
     1 | 2013-12-10  | (4,1,2013-12-10,90.76) |       4
     2 | 2013-12-10  | (5,2,2013-12-10,90.76) |       5
     2 | 2013-12-06  | (6,2,2013-12-06,90.76) |       6
     3 | 2013-12-06  | (7,3,2013-12-06,90.76) |       7
     3 | 2013-12-06  | (8,3,2013-12-06,90.76) |       8
```

i want a query which will give num,i_id for the records which have different dates for same num.
It should return num-1,2 and the corresponding i_id.
How should i proceed?

Comment: Can you give the the output for this sample? Your question isn't too clear.

Comment: @Mureinik : output should be   num | date_         |           s            | i_id 
-------+-------------+------------------------+---------
     1 | 2013-12-12  | (2,1,2013-12-12,80.56) |       2
     1 | 2013-12-10  | (4,1,2013-12-10,90.76) |       4
     2 | 2013-12-10  | (5,2,2013-12-10,90.76) |       5
     2 | 2013-12-06  | (6,2,2013-12-06,90.76) |       6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work in PostgreSQL with an version number >= 9.0

```
SELECT
  num
, array_to_string(array_agg(i_id ORDER BY num), ',')
FROM a
GROUP BY num
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/25502/5

And it look like in your comment that you want to have the MAX(date_)

```
SELECT
  num
, MAX(date_)
, array_to_string(array_agg(i_id ORDER BY num), ',')
FROM a
GROUP BY num
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/25502/6

Answer (score 0):

```
select num, group_concat(i_id) as iids
from your_table
group by num
having count(distinct date_) > 1
```

Comment: thanks . if the same query goes in postgresql will group_concat() work? or should i use array to string ?

Comment: There is no `group_concat` in postgresql.